# How do I add a browser history state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange, browser-state

So I see a lot of people recommend the hidden-`iFrame` hack that is [jQuery history plugin](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) but all I really need is the other half of this technique:

```
function whenItemIsClicked()
    {
    window.location.hash = this.id;
    //some other stuff, like Ajax
    }

//and then, if page is reloaded...
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loc = window.location.hash;
    //if there happens to be a hash, navigate to corresponding content
    if(loc != '') $(loc).click();
});
```

Both of these work great. Now, I'd like to attach these two lines

```
  var loc = window.location.hash;
  if(loc != '') $(loc).click();
```

to an event, but it seems there isn't one that will be triggered consistently by the back button. Is there a way to add a browser history state that will save the present URL so the above technique will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an event called [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) though not everyone supports it yet, but...[there's a plugin by Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) to solve that issue.

The plugin makes it work cross-browser by using `window.onhashchange` (the native event) if it's there. If not, it polls every 50ms and triggers the event itself, if the hash changes.  Using [the plugin](http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/tree/v1.3), your code would look like this:

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
  var loc = window.location.hash;
  if(loc != '') $(loc).click();    
});
```

You just need that code in one place. You can trigger it once in `document.ready` by just firing the event after it's bound like above doing this:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).hashchange();
});
```